# How to get last week top tracks of an artist using last.fm API?

Tags: api, last.fm

I want to fetch the `last week top tracks` of an artist using the last.fm API but I don't see any relevant method call for that.

I looked at `artist.getTopTracks` method but it returns the overall top tracks of an artist.

So, is there any way I can fetch just the last week top tracks using the API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately no way to get this info via their API. Bit strange indeed as the last week top tracks chart is listed default on an artist page at the last.fm website. So you have to use some good old web scraping techniques.

Comment: Thanks. I will look into web scraping